# Why does the <li> element not change color and width when I hover the mouse over it after hovering over the image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the snippet that is causing trouble:

```js
function focuss() {
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    x[i].style.color = "red";
    x[i].style.width = "340px";
    x[i].style.left = "-25px";
  }
}

function unfocuss() {
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    x[i].style.color = "white";
    x[i].style.width = "290px";
    x[i].style.left = "0px";
  }
}
```

```css
li {
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
  height: 33px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  width: 290px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  font-size: 21px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 3px;

}
li:hover {
  width: 340px;
  left: -25px;
  background-color: yellow;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <a>
    <li>GALLERY</li>
  </a>
  <a>
    <li>STATISTICS</li>
  </a>
  <a>
    <li>PLACES TO VISIT</li>
  </a>
  <a>
    <li>HOME</li>
  </a>
</ul>

<img src="f1.jpg" id="img1" onmouseover="focuss()" onmouseout="unfocuss()">
```

When I hover my mouse directly over the `<li>`s after loading the page, the styles of these `<li>` elements change. However, once I hover over the image and then hover over the `<li>`s again, there is no change. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your markup is wrong: the anchor should be inside the `li`. not even sure if that will fix it, but it should be done

Comment: @dan08 But I don't want only the text inside the list elements to be anchors. i want the complete list element to be an anchor.

Comment: Then you should do that with CSS not invalid HTML. A quick example: https://jsfiddle.net/xpbdruh5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the inline styles you are applying in the unfocuss() method are overwriting the CSS :hover styles. I've copied your example below with !important in the hover CSS. I would recommend using !important sparingly, but it fixes the specific problem you have stated.

```js
function focuss() {
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    x[i].style.color = "red";
    x[i].style.width = "340px";
    x[i].style.left = "-25px";
  }
}

function unfocuss() {
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    x[i].style.color = "white";
    x[i].style.width = "290px";
    x[i].style.left = "0px";
  }
}
```

```css
li {
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
  height: 33px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  width: 290px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  font-size: 21px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 3px;

}
li:hover {
  width: 340px !important;
  left: -25px !important;
  background-color: yellow !important;
  color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <a>
    <li>GALLERY</li>
  </a>
  <a>
    <li>STATISTICS</li>
  </a>
  <a>
    <li>PLACES TO VISIT</li>
  </a>
  <a>
    <li>HOME</li>
  </a>
</ul>

<img src="f1.jpg" id="img1" onmouseover="focuss()" onmouseout="unfocuss()">
```

Answer (score 1):

As Khris points out, your manually-added styles are clobbering the styles in your CSS.

Instead of manipulating the styles, modify the elements' classes. This is a much cleaner and less redundant approach:

```js
function focuss() {
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].classList.add('highlight');
  }
}

function unfocuss() {
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].classList.remove('highlight');
  }
}
```

```css
li {
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
  height: 33px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  width: 290px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  font-size: 21px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 3px;

}
li:hover, li.highlight {
  width: 340px;
  left: -25px;
  background-color: yellow;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <a>
    <li>GALLERY</li>
  </a>
  <a>
    <li>STATISTICS</li>
  </a>
  <a>
    <li>PLACES TO VISIT</li>
  </a>
  <a>
    <li>HOME</li>
  </a>
</ul>

<img src="f1.jpg" id="img1" onmouseover="focuss()" onmouseout="unfocuss()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Reset the inline styles when `onmouseout()`

```js
function focuss() {
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    x[i].style.color = "red";
    x[i].style.width = "340px";
    x[i].style.left = "-25px";
  }
}

function unfocuss() {
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style = "";
    
  }
}
```

```css
li {
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
  height: 33px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  width: 290px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  font-size: 21px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 3px;

}
li:hover {
  width: 340px;
  left: -25px;
  background-color: yellow;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <a>
    <li>GALLERY</li>
  </a>
  <a>
    <li>STATISTICS</li>
  </a>
  <a>
    <li>PLACES TO VISIT</li>
  </a>
  <a>
    <li>HOME</li>
  </a>
</ul>

<img src="f1.jpg" id="img1" onmouseover="focuss()" onmouseout="unfocuss()">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could skip the script and use CSS `flexbox`

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.flex img {
  order: 1
}
li {
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
  height: 33px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  width: 290px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  font-size: 21px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 3px;
}
img:hover + ul li,
li:hover {
  width: 340px;
  left: -25px;
  background-color: yellow;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <img src="f1.jpg" id="img1">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a>GALLERY</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>STATISTICS</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>PLACES TO VISIT</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>HOME</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```